# Can Chat-bot be achieved on android on Hangout app or any other default apps other than Facebook Messenger

Tags: android, hangouts-api

**What i need:** I need to read messages of Hangout or any other default apps of android, so i send reply back according to the messages. Although Hangout api not giving access to read the messages (Based on my research), but Gmail giving api for read, modify and send emails.

Is there any other alternative to do such kind of work with internet messaging for reading the messaging on backend service to send reply from my own application.

Looking forward for serious answers, any help could be appreciated thanks in Advance.

Comment: Considering the privacy issues and according to privacy policies of these apps, no third party app or organisation can be given access to user's messages. If you manage to find any API that violates these terms, you can become millionaire by suing them.

Comment: @MohammedAtif But recently microsoft showed some kind of work in there conference in dubai, means there should be something we can read content

Comment: Can you elaborate or provide a link of the demonstration. I am really keen to know this. Thanks